# Spring Boot Actuator Kubernetes Probes returning 404

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to use [Kubernetes Probes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-kubernetes-probes) from Spring Boot Actuator, but it isn't working.

I have set the following in application.properties:

```
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=probes
management.endpoint.health.group.ping.include=ping
management.endpoint.health.group.liveness.include=livenessState
management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.include=readinessState
```

The groups are listed as expected:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/actuator/probes
{"status":"UP","groups":["liveness","ping","readiness"]}
```

And `ping` works as expected:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/actuator/probes/ping
{"status":"UP"}
```

**However both `liveness` and `readiness` return `Status Code: 404` and `Content-Length: 0`.**

---

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `2.3.1.RELEASE`.

The probes I want are documented in the list of [Auto-configured HealthIndicators](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-health-indicators).

The feature is also described at: https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/25/liveness-and-readiness-probes-with-spring-boot.

I've tried several spellings of `livenessState`, inluding `livenessProbe` (which is in the blog post), with no effect.

Here's a related answer, but it doesn't directly address my problem: [Kubernetes - Liveness and Readiness probe implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62585531/86967)

*What bit of configuration am I missing?*

---

### Update

There is some verbiage in the linked sites that indicates a potential clue...

> If deployed in a Kubernetes environment, actuator will gather the "Liveness" and "Readiness" information...

Maybe this indicates that the probes *only work* if deployed in a Kubernetes environment -- although I don't know how that would be detected or why that would be the case.

Comment: Following the link in a comment below, I discovered that there was a breaking change introduced in 2.3.2: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22562#issuecomment-663824004

Answer (score 28):

Adding following configurations worked for me (by trial and error)

```
management.health.livenessstate.enabled=true
management.health.readinessstate.enabled=true
```

If you are running locally, you will also need to add

```
management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true
```

I am using `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `2.3.2.RELEASE`.

Comment: Even with this configuration on 2.3.2.RELEASE there is still a regression regarding the readinessstate still returning 404. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22562

Answer (score 6):

It is correct to use `include=livenessState` or `include=readinessState`.  The example [here](https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/25/liveness-and-readiness-probes-with-spring-boot) (which shows `include=livenessProbe`) is wrong.

I identified the correct name by trial-and-error -- checking the result while ***running in a Kubernetes environment***.

```
management.endpoint.health.group.exploratory.include=livenessState,readinessState,ping
management.endpoint.health.group.exploratory.show-details=always
```

By some magic, *and for no obvious reason*, these indicators aren't available when you do a standard local run -- and you get `404` for health groups that have no available includes.

For reference:

- [Auto-configured HealthIndicators (list)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-health-indicators)
- [ApplicationAvailabilityBean which is the source of truth for liveness/readiness](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/availability/ApplicationAvailabilityBean.html)

Comment: I think the reason the indicators don't show up when run locally is part of a broader feature in which you only see _relevant_ health indicators.  For example, it doesn't tell you the "redis" status unless you've attempted to connect to a Redis host.

Comment: Following the link in another comment, I discovered that there was a breaking change introduced in 2.3.2: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22562#issuecomment-663824004