# Kubernetes: Readiness Check with httpGet

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, readinessprobe

I am quite confused about readiness probe. Suppose I use httpGet with /health as the probing endpoint. Once the readiness check returns 500, the server will stop serving traffic. Then how can the /health endpoint work? In other words, once a readiness check fails, how can it ever work again since it can no longer answer to future /health checks?

I guess one valid explanation is that the path is invoked locally? (i.e. not through the https:${ip and port}/health)

Comment: you should use /health endpoint in livenessProbe so kubernetes will kill and start another pod.

for readiness you can use another endpoint related to your business logic.

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46029885/10020419

Answer (score 3):

You have typo.. you said :

> Once the readiness check returns 500, the **server** will stop serving traffic.

However, it should be :

> Once the readiness check returns 500, the **k8s service** will stop serving traffic.

[image]

k8s service behaves like a load balancer for multi-pods.

- If pod is ready, an endpoint will be created for the ready pod, and the traffic will be received.
- If pod is not ready, its endpoint will be removed and it will not more receive traffic.

While **Readiness Probe** decides to forward traffic or not, **Liveness Probe** decides to restart the Pod or not.

If you want to get rid off unhealthy Pod, you have to specify also **Liveness Probe**.

### So let's summarize:

To get full HA deployment you need 3 things together:

- Pod are managed by **Deployment** which will maintain a number of replicas.
- **Liveness Probe** will help to remove/restart the unlheathy pod.. After somtime ( 6 restarts), the Pod will be unhealthy and the Deployment will take care to bring new one.
- **Readiness Probe** will help forward traffic to only ready pods : Either at beginning of run, or at the end of run ( graceful shutdown).